# Multi-Calculus 3 Question Level curves

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I don't know how to start this problem? Any hints? I don't even think I know what it is saying....

Let $f(x,y)$ be a differentiable function, $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Suppose $f$ has a smooth level curve $f(x,y)=c$, parametrized by the path $r(t) = <x(t),y(t)>$, $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Show that $\nabla f $ satisfies: $\nabla f$ is orthogonal $r'(t)$ at every $t$

Comment: You mean $\nabla f$ not $\Delta f$?

Comment: Yes, thanks you!

Comment: Differentiate both sides

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use chain rule to compute
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}f(x(t), y(t))= \frac{d}{dt} c
\end{align}